# How did I review stuff incorrectly?

Tags: support, reviewing

I am suspended from reviewing because I reviewed stuff incorrectly. All the stuff I reviewed ended up getting deleted by a moderator and on all of them I had:

- Upvoted a comment saying that’s not how things are said
- Left a comment asking for better

Here are the links for the questions I reviewed wrongly:

- [Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/297510) to "Sharing game between devices?"
- [Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/297513) to "Blocks mysteriously disappearing in minecraft?"
- [Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/297516) to "How can I restart my game?"
- [Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/297521) to "When being a werewolf, is there a way I can heal my self?"
- [Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/297553): "How do you give a name, lore, and enchantments in Minecraft using a single Command Block? (Bedrock Edition 1.16)"

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? Is upvoting someone else’s comment saying the question was not asked correctly not enough?

Comment: Fourth one doesn't work...

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 fixed it

Comment: In Question (#5) you seem to have clicked on 'No Action Needed' instead of 'I'm Done'. Click on 'I'm Done' after you've done an action in the review queue, like voting or editing, to mark it as 'Reviewed'. When reviewing make sure to check the post for issues like formatting and 'Thank you!'/fluff/chatty comments (as per this [meta post](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/)) and edit it if necessary. That question has an unremoved 'Thank you!' comment. Also, the OP has used the <> characters to emphasize the custom name of the weapon, I'd edit it to use quotes instead to improve the formatting.

Comment: @galacticninja no I think he wants the name to have the >< on it and instead if changing those to quotes, maybe put quotes around it (i.e. “>xyz<“)

Comment: XD now I feel really dumb I just realized it literally says on the notice exactly what I did wrong lmao sorry

Comment: @Penguin Aye, you are probably right on the <> characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the First Posts and Late Answers review queues, only 1 "Reviewed" or "No Action Needed" review takes the item out of the queue. While comments stating that a post is not an answer are nice, all of these posts required further attention. In these cases, the correct action would have been to **flag the post as Not An Answer**, marking them for further review in the Low Quality Posts and moderator queues.

The last one is of course a question, which is slightly different but similar. In that case, rather than just posting a comment that their question has an answer in another place, the correct action would have been to **flag the post as a Duplicate**.

We understand that it can be frustrating to be locked out of the queues, but correct reviews are important for us to maintain quality on the site, and flags are essential to identifying low quality posts.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I wasn’t really frustrated just wanted to make sure I didn’t get unlocked and then keep doing the same thing that got me locked. Thanks!